# How to show a part of details/body to read in Laravel so that I can use a clickable link to read the full body?

Tags: laravel, post, laravel-5, view

Sorry for this Very silly question. But I badly need it. I'm passing post details from the posts table using this in the controller:

```
$posts = post::where('status',1)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(5);
```

In my posts table there are title,subtitle and body.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
                <div class="post-preview">

                    <a href="{{ route('post',$post->slug) }}">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            {{ $post->title }}
                        </h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                            {{ $post->subtitle }}
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans() }} </p>

                </div>
                @endforeach
```

so it is showing the title,subtitle and time. but I want to show the 2/3 lines from the body attribute, then want to use "see more" link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use helper class `str_limit` to limit your text by character count.

To limit in 100 character you can use-

```
{{ str_limit($post->body, 100) }}
```

[str_limit in laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-limit)